# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to show tooltip for my dojo button, I have tried the following code but getting error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`. Please solve this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
    <script>
      var map,toolbar,toolTip;

      require(["esri/map",
               "esri/toolbars/draw",
               "esri/graphic",
               "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
               "esri/Color",
               "dojo/on",
               "dojo/dom",
               "dijit/Tooltip",
               "dojo/domReady!"], 
          function(Map,Draw,Graphic,SimpleLineSymbol,Color,on,dom,Tooltip) {
          map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",  
          center: [72, 25.75], 
          zoom: 5
        });
        //map.on("load",createToolbar);



       dojo.connect(Info, "onclick", createToolbar);



        function createToolbar() {

          toolbar = new Draw(map, { showTooltips: true });
          toolbar.activate(Draw.RECTANGLE);
          toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);

        }

        function() {
        toolTip = new Tooltip({
        connectId: ["Info"],
        label: "value <b>Draw PolyLine</b>"    
       });
       }

        function addToMap(evt) {
          //alert("Index");
          toolbar.deactivate();

          var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(
       SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
       new Color([255,0,0]),3);

          var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, sls);
          map.graphics.add(graphic);
       }

      });


    </script>
  </head>

  <body> 
    <div id="map">
        <div> <button id="Info" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"><b>Draw PolyLine</b></button>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Tooltip" data-dojo-props="connectId:'Info',position:['below']"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks not like a GIS/ArcGIS specific problem, but like a problem with malformatted javascript code.

Answer (score 5):

The function definition below (before addToMap)

```
function() {
    toolTip = new Tooltip({
    connectId: ["Info"],
    label: "value <b>Draw PolyLine</b>"    
});
```

throws the syntax error.

You have to add a name to that function definition, like

```
function createTooltip() {
    toolTip = new Tooltip({
    connectId: ["Info"],
    label: "value <b>Draw PolyLine</b>"    
});
```

Comment: Mine was the answer to msurya question. The syntax error is there, in the function() { like. Sorry for being too short.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the code executed by your `addToMap(evt)` function in curly brackets.The problem is that you missed the closing bracket at the end of the function:

```
function addToMap(evt) {
      //alert("Index");
      toolbar.deactivate();
} //<- expected token
```

So your browser expects to see the closing bracket, but it moves along to the next line and gets

```
var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol( //Not "{", so it's an unexpected token.
```

EDIT:
You have to pay attention to the closing brackets and paranthesis, otherwise your code won't work.
You missed a few more:

```
zoom: 5
});
}); //<- you should add } to close the function(Map,Draw,Graphic,...) 
    //and ) to close the require
//map.on("load",createToolbar);
```